# Is it possible to mirror a MediaWiki article from another wiki?

Tags: synchronization, mediawiki, mirror, extension

I have two MediaWiki installations on two different domains, both on the same server but with different databases.

Is there a feature or extension that will allow me to automatically mirror the contents of one wiki to the other, and have the mirrored version stay up to date?

I want to be able to automatically sync the Privacy Policy page because the policy applies to both domains.

Comment: Maybe the [include extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Include) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Is it capable of "including" only the body of the article, and not the sidebar, etc?

Comment: I've got no experience with MediaWiki or this extension, but I'm sure you'll find out.

Answer (score 2):

Just set [`$wgEnableScaryTranscluding = true`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgEnableScaryTranscluding) in your `LocalSettings.php` and ensure the source wiki is a local interwiki (if you don't know how, use the [Interwiki extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Interwiki) which offers a nice interface).

For instance [this is a user page](http://wiki.wikimedia.it/wiki/Utente:Sannita) which is automatically copied (transcluded) from another wiki.

Despite the name, the interwiki transclusion isn't that scary at all: it's used by various wikis including MITRE wikis.